# Should I Create One Big Table or Many Small Tables for Database

Tags: database-design

I am currently writing a web application and I am trying to design my DB for storing information that is going to be gather from the web application.

The web application currently is designed to present the user with only **ONE questionnaire** which the user will have to fill out. The questionnaire the user has to complete will be based on several factors.

There will be 4 different questionnaires total.

Each questionnaire will have different number of questions.

So my question is:

Should I design 4 different tables for each questionaire or should I create 1 table that will have enough rows and columns to store the response of all 4 questionaires? Which option will be most efficient and least taxing on a system.

If I break them into 4 different tables based on questionaire, what would be the best solution for a primary key

I already have tables for Users, etc..

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Please don't tag both `mysql` and `sql-server` unless you genuinely have a question that relates the two. If you could remove the tag that doesn't apply to your question, it would be a favor to all who come across it. **Additionally,** questions that are opinion-based or too broad will most likely be closed. As this question isn't directly relating to an issue that needs debugging/solving, and is rather an open-answer question, it doesn't really belong on SO.

Comment: A design for a single questionnaire should (likely) require more than one table; a design for multiple questionnaires should only require one additional table, and an extra field in the tables used for a single questionnaire to identify which rows in those tables belong to which questionnaire.

Comment: This question, as written, is probably too broad.  Are you using an ORM?  Are these tables insert-only or do they get updated?  What are your scalability requirements?

Comment: And, just to piggy-back, as a personal preference: I'd have a table called `Questionnaires` which has all information relating just to the questionaire itself - the title, for example. Then, a second table named `Questions` with a column for all information pertaining to the question. A third table that links the two, which has two columns: `Questionnaire_ID` and `Question_ID`, to determine which questions go on which Questionnaire, allowing a "many-to-many" relationship.

Answer (score 0):

A wise man said: You can tell the quality of a database by the count of its tables... Well, this is - for sure! - not true in all cases, but *put-all-in-one* is almost ever the wrong concept.

Try not to repeat data!

There is one table for the questionair (an ID as primary key, its name, time of creation, some metadata)

One table for all possible questions (ID, QuestionText, Type of answer [yes/no, numeric scala, choice, free text, ...]...)

One table to connect these two (QuestionairID,QuestionID,...)

If the answers are bound to given lists you might need a table for possible answers, which - again - need an own table to map them to their questions

And so on...

This is called *relational database schema*

You should really read and learn about this before you start to design your data!

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not really sure this kind of design would need a many-to-many relationship, a "parent-child" relationship would probably be more appropriate. I would think questions probably wouldn't exist independently of the questionnaires that contain them (having a reference to the "parent" questionnaire), and the repetition of identical questions (with identical answer sets) across multiple questionnaires would be too rare for a many-to-many to provide any benefits.

Comment: @Uueerdo Might be... This depends on the questionairs... If this is about 4 different products the questions might be almost the same. If this is about family, job, holiday and movies you are right. For a small student's project less might be more... But - before the start - one should at least know the principles...

Comment: True, if the project were for a company that does customer satisfaction surveys, there would be likely a lot of overlap on the questions; it does benefit the designer to know the _use case_ and/or acceptance criteria.